# pg_dump fails with "LOG: server process (PID 6055) was terminated by signal 9: Killed"

Tags: postgresql

trying to export database with pg_dump
I use parameter "-j 30" to speed up export but issue is that system kills Postgres processes

```
kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 6055 (postmaster) score 508 or sacrifice child
kernel: Killed process 6055 (postmaster), UID 26, total-vm:37128640kB, anon-rss:11666428kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:13056896kB
```

we have work_mem 500M, and it's like 15Gb per all processes, though server has 48Gb RAM.
Q is - what database memory structure may be decreased  to prevent heavy swap?

Comment: Have you got a lot of Large Objects?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe not large, but tons of small, like millions of tables and indexes (and it's 9.6 :( )

Comment: I am talking about [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html), sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

We have found the causer : it was the pg_dump process, it took over 33GB of RAM during metadata export, a bit of more RAM saved the export.